# A linux program that uses memory

Tags: linux, memory

I need it execute a certain kind of linux program from the terminal. The only thing the linux program needs to do is use more and more memory. Are there any programs like that?

Comment: trying to do something like [this](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/29/how-to-mess-up-your-pc/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798330/maximum-memory-which-malloc-can-allocate/4735795#4735795) on StackOverflow:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
int *p;
while(1) {
    int inc=1024*1024*sizeof(char);
    p=(int*) calloc(1,inc);
    if(!p) break;
    }
}
```

run

```
$ gcc memtest.c
$ ./a.out
```

upon running, this code fills up ones RAM until killed by the kernel. Using calloc instead of malloc to prevent "lazy evaluation". Ideas taken from this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383059/malloc-memory-questions

This code quickly filled my RAM (4Gb) and then in about 2 minutes my 20Gb swap partition before it died. This works on 64bit Linux. If you use a 32bit OS, it will have a limit of 2 or 4GB before it dies.

Answer (score 9):

how about [a fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) ?

else something that creates a series of ever larger ram disks?
You can create a ram disk with

> mkdir /tmp/ramdisk; chmod 777 /tmp/ramdisk
>
> mount -t tmpfs -o size=256M tmpfs /tmp/ramdisk/

to create a 256 mb ram disk. you could probably script a script that will make a series of ram disks, and fill them repeatedly up until whatever you need would happen

Comment: +1 for fork bomb - probably the most simple solution here. OP never mentioned monitoring the used memory.

Comment: Fork bombs typically kill the system because of CPU constraints, not RAM. It will eventually fill up your RAM as well, though, if you want to go that route...

Answer (score 4):

Save the following as `mem.c`, then run `gcc -o mem mem.c`, then run `./mem`. It allocates 100MB of memory every second. It does nothing else. You can change the number of seconds its sleeps or how many MB it allocates by changing the numbers below.

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <memory.h>
#define MB 1024 * 1024
int main() {
    while (1) {
        void *p = malloc( 100*MB );
        memset(p,0, 100*MB );
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
OK, tested and updated.

Answer (score 3):

Most answers recommend compiling something; my approach was for an embedded device that already ran basic GNU tools and for which I could not compile something custom. I answered this here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254976/30731

> If you have basic GNU tools (`head` and `tail`) or BusyBox on Linux, you can do this to **fill a certain amount of free memory**:
>
> ```
> </dev/zero head -c BYTES | tail
>
> # Protip: use $((1024**3*7)) to calculate 7GiB easily
> </dev/zero head -c $((1024**3*7)) | tail
> ```
>
> This works because tail needs to keep the current line in memory, in case it turns out to be the last line. The line, read from `/dev/zero` which outputs only null bytes and no newlines, will be infinitely long, but is limited by `head` to `BYTES` bytes, thus `tail` will use only that much memory. For a more precise amount, you will need to check how much RAM `head` and `tail` itself use on your system and subtract that.
>
> To just quickly **run out of RAM completely**, you can remove the limiting `head` part:
>
> ```
> tail /dev/zero
> ```
>
> If you want to also **add a duration**, this can be done quite easily in `bash` (will not work in `sh`):
>
> ```
> cat <( </dev/zero head -c BYTES) <(sleep SECONDS) | tail
> ```
>
> The `<(command)` thing seems to be little known but is often extremely useful, more info on it here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html
>
> Then for the use of `cat`: `cat` will wait for inputs to complete until exiting, and by keeping one of the pipes open, it will keep `tail` alive.
>
> If you have `pv` and want to **slowly increase RAM use**:
>
> ```
> </dev/zero head -c BYTES | pv -L BYTES_PER_SEC | tail
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> </dev/zero head -c $((1024**3)) | pv -L $((1024**2)) | tail
> ```
>
> Will use up to a gigabyte at a rate of a megabyte per second. As an added bonus, **`pv` will show you the current rate of use and the total use so far**. Of course this can also be done with previous variants:
>
> ```
> </dev/zero head -c BYTES | pv | tail
> ```
>
> Just inserting the `| pv |` part will show you the current status (throughput and total by default).
>
> ---
>
> Credits to [falstaff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200982/how-to-generate-a-memory-shortage-using-bash-script/34755981#comment78484190_34755981) for contributing a variant that is even simpler and more broadly compatible (like with BusyBox).

Comment: For the downvoter: I would love to hear any feedback to make my future posts more useful.

Comment: I like this very much. Here's my variant: `function usefor() { grep -q . <(dd if=/dev/zero bs=$1 count=1 2>/dev/null; sleep $2); }`. Then I can use units like this: `usefor 512M infinity`

Answer (score 2):

There's a utility called `stress` which does this, among other things.  `apt-get install stress` from Debian.

Answer (score 2):

[eatmemory](https://github.com/julman99/eatmemory) is a very simple program that we use to test low memory conditions on DB servers
I Hope it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You could use mprime, which is, IIRC, a linux port of Prime95 of overclocking fame.  mprime (and Prime95) will allow you to stress test the memory and CPU of your computer system.  In addition, you can specify exactly how much memory you want mprime to use (to overflow into swap space, if you like).

Find mprime and prime95 [here](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/).  I apologize in advance for the state of the website's navigation.